# Creating multiport block ram in Vivado + Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, convolution, vivado

I want to do convolution in my FPGA.
I do have an array, where the image is stored, which then is clocked out to a screen via VGA.
I want to compute the convolution the moment a pixel is clocked out, such that I only need multipliers the size of the convolution kernel.

However, I don't know how I can create a block ram, such that I can access for example 9 addresses (if I was using a 3x3 convolution kernel) at the same time. Is that possible in Vivado? I am currently using the Block Ram Generator.

Comment: You can try exploring [this](https://timetoexplore.net/blog/block-ram-in-verilog-with-vivado)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is read two values from two different addresses and for that you have to use dual-ported RAM.

But most of the time you need one port for writing the video data and the second port for reading it.

To read 9 location you have to either:

- Have 9 different memories
- Make sure all the data is in one address and make the memory 9 times as wide.

**But there is still hope.**
In video you get the horizontal pixels one after another. This means that for a 3x3 convolution you can build three small 3-stage pixel pipelines from registers:

[image]

<sub>(Yes, I put some code in Vivado and use the elaborated schematic for that)</sub>

Now you have access to the data of 9 pixels at a time. You could even omit one stage but that might upset your convolution timing.

**The final dampener**
This looks so simple but for this you need to have access to the data of **three video lines** at a time. Thus "all" you need to do now is build a system which remember the data for two lines and once you get to line three, re-read the data from the previous two lines and put them with the data of line 3 in the little system shown above. Thus you need at least 2 independent dual-ported memory banks which can each hold one line of video data.

I know this works because I built something just like that last week.